# Debugging COM+ in Delphi 2009 : the dllhost.exe /ProcessID does not work

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2009, com+

I am writing a COM+ component in Delphi 2009 on Windows 8. (I will move on to XE3 soon but for now it's D2009).

I have had quite a few IDE freezes when debugging regular simple forms applicaitions, mainly when closing the application after having stopped in a breakpoint and continued running the following code, but other than that D2009 works fine.

Now, the problem I have is that I am unable to debug the COM+ component. A new instance of this component is created from another forms application. If I specify that form applicaition in the "Run" options dialog of the project, it all works fine but no stop at the breakpoints in the COM+ object. I then found online about the way to debug by putting dllhost.exe in "run" with "/ProcessID: GUID" in the parameters. I double checked everything and all I see when I hit F9 is "Thread entered" then "Thread exited" in the debug console. Still not stopping at any breakpoints which all show up as out of running scope.

How can I do it then please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check your components COM+ configuration. To correctly debug need Pool Size = 1 (Pooling & Recycling) and the component identity in "interactive user"